# Disabling Datagrid selection in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

i have an array list of data which i am showing in spark data grid.

once i select an idem and click on a button that i have linked with datagrid it adds a panel on screen. I want to disable this selection i-e to tell that this item panel have already been added. Any ideas how can i do that?

best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try   `this.contains(child:DisplayObject)` It Determines whether the specified display object is a child of the DisplayObjectContainer instance or the instance itself. The search includes the entire display list including this DisplayObjectContainer instance. Grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on each return true.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a `.disable()` function on datagrids, or you can use `return false;` so that it won't proceed.